# bundle a script that contains other webpack output

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack to bundle my app. Since my app contains two saperated files, I decided to use webpack with multiple compilers like in this example: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler

Now there is a need to unify those files. My output should be one script file, and that script have to contain the second script as a string (escaped).

This is what I've done:

```
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig());

compiler.plugin('done', () => {
    var bundleA = fs.readFileSync(`${paths.build.scriptA}/bundle.js`, 'utf8');
    var bundleB = fs.readFileSync(`${paths.build.scriptB}/bundle.js`, 'utf8');
    bundleA = hostBundle
        .replace('BUNDLE B CONTENT HERE', JSON.stringify(bundleB));

    fs.writeFileSync(`${paths.build.scriptA}/bundle.js`, bundleA);
});
compiler.run(function(error, stats) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error');
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```

This code works perfectly as long as I build the project. The problem is that when I run it using webpack devserver, it doesn't works.

Is this the best solution for my need?
How can I fix webpack devserver?